# Using PlanetScope basic scenes with the ArcGIS mensuration tools

Tags: arcgis-desktop, metadata, planet

I would like to measure vertical heights from shadows in PlanetScope basic scenes. To do this, I am using the mensuration tools in the analysis window in ArcGIS desktop.

When I load the PlanetScope scene into arcmap, I find that the "Base to top height" tool is active, however the "Top to shadow height" tool is greyed out. As I understand it, this means ArcMap is recognising the RPCs in the *_RPC.TXT file, but not the solar azimuth/altiude data in the json file. I was wondering if anybody knows how to make ArcMp recognise the solar illumination information to activate the "Top to shadow height" tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the ArcGIS toolbox for PlanetScope and RapidEye imagery:

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=7a60feff875645b781f4683efe3a437a

This allows you to load the .xml file as a dataset, which provides all the relevant metadata. This activates the mensuration tools that need illumination information.